# string to numeric array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, eval

From one program I generate bunch of data and it is stored in a file. An example of the file's contents is

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

As you can see, the data has the exact form of an array. Later in another program I want to read the data and use it. I am using

```
text_file = open('DataFile.txt')
lines = text_file.readlines() #We have only 1 line but this doesn't matter
```

The variable `lines` is an array of 1 element which is the string `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. I want this string to be again a numeric array. Just with the same delimiters etc. How can I do this?

Comment: `import ast; ast.literal_eval(the_text)`

Comment: Yup, thanks! that works. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer and since all are correct I'll accept the one that was published first. Thanks all anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> mystr = '[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]'
>>> x = literal_eval(mystr)
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html) module provides a [`literal_eval(repr)`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function that **safely** evaluates any python *literal*:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]")
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> ast.literal_eval("19e6")
19000000.0
```

Alternatively, you could use [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
>>> json.loads("[[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9]]")
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

The `json` solution is quite *faster* to `literal_eval`:

```
In [1]: import ast, json

In [2]: %timeit ast.literal_eval("[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]")
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.5 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit json.loads("[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]")
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.16 us per loop

In [4]: 33.5 / 4.16
Out[4]: 8.052884615384615
In [5]: big_list_text = '[{}]'.format(','.join(["[1,2,3,4]"] * 1000))

In [6]: %timeit ast.literal_eval(big_list_text)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.6 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit json.loads(big_list_text)
1000 loops, best of 3: 485 us per loop

In [8]: 14600 / 485
Out[8]: 30.103092783505154
```

As you can see `json.loads` is significantly faster than `ast.literal_eval`, although they parse different things which only happen to be the same when dealing with *simple* list literals.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `eval` helps you:

```
In [1]: s = '[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]'

In [2]: eval(s)
Out[2]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: `eval` is unsafe. What if someone put `__import__("subprocess").Popen("rm -rf", shell=True)` as the first line of the file? (Answer - your hard disk would be wiped).